# What are those lines under some anime characters eyes supposed to be / mean?

Tags: manga-history, full-metal-panic

Some anime characters have lines under their eyes. I was wondering what it represents? Is it supposed to be like having dark circles under the eyes like some people in real life or?

Below is a perfect example, both the male and female characters have it so it couldn't be a beauty thing.

[image: Example, both have the lines]

What does it mean?

Comment: This is answered on [meta], of all places: see the "Did You Know?" at the end of the post "[Now Announcing: A New Initiative for Anime & Manga SE Engagement (it's a work in progress~)](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4360/now-announcing-a-new-initiative-for-anime-manga-se-engagement-its-a-work-in)".

Comment: Also see this question here on the main site: [What are those weird three-line blushy things on some anime/manga characters cheeks?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/45087/what-are-those-weird-three-line-blushy-things-on-some-anime-manga-characters-che)

Comment: Maybe blush or light shadow.

Answer (score 3):

It's just part of a style that was prevalent in the 1990s. It disappeared during the early 2000s, when anime transitioned towards digital.

- 1991, 3x3 Eyes

  [image]
- 1991, Otaku no Video

  [image]
- 1991, Sukeban Deka

  [image]
- 1994, Shounan Junai-gumi

  [image]
- 1995, Shin Seiki Evangelion

  [image]
- 1997, Fortune Quest

  [image]
- 1999, Chivas 1-2-3

  [image]
- 1999, Iketeru Futari

  [image]
- 2002, Tenshi na Konamaiki

  [image]
- 2004, Akane Maniax

  [image]

Answer (score 2):

**I was wondering what it represents?** I've been researching and I could not find any information or reason regarding what they are exactly or why they are placed underneath the eyes. This, however, seems to be *an anime-only thing* and, *possibly, an artistic style or preference, unique to the one who drew them*. Below is the cover for the first light volume, which do not have those lines.

[image]

**Is it supposed to be like having dark circles under the eyes like some people in real life or something else?** No, they are not dark circles under the eyes. Dark circles under the eyes are different, and can be seen clearly. An example is from Watamote. [image]

They are also not [underlashes](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/discussion.php?id=ar99irkz5p3d7d1humpkh4x5) as both characters also have them and they are drawn separately. So far, I think the only way we'll know is if the one who drew them reveals the reason and purpose for placing those lines.

Answer (score 1):

So if anyone is still wondering, it's meant to represent the blush in the cheeks of the face, due to manga having a large influence and shading could only be obtained from black and white, the lines are meant to be the blush, and it carried over to anime, and now it is not only a stylistic choice, but some artists do it for the same reason, and that is to signify the blush, just like how blush over the nose is drawing with lines.

As a guide, dark-blue is usually when a character is embarrassed or tired, (Sometimes bruises), red means that the character face is blushing either from embarrassment, or due to being angry, and black means its just the tone of the face.

**TL;DR:** *It is drawn to be like the blush on the a persons cheek*